# HQL insert ... select with parameters

Tags: hibernate, jpa, hql, insert-select

I need to execute batch insert select statement:

```
Query query = em
        .createQuery(
        "insert into EntityA (a,b,entity_field) select t.a, t.b, 
         :entity_field from EntityA t where ...");
query.setParameter("entity_field ", entity);
```

**Field entity_field is not a primitive type in EntityA**
I am getting java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.QueryException: number of select types did not match those for insert.

Is there some way to do that?

Comment: No, it works for primitive types.

Answer (score 1):

when you put in select field a not primitive type it's decomposite in all properties. So you have a query like this:

```
INSERT INTO (a, b, entity_field)
SELECT t.a, t.b, entity_field.field1, entity_field.field2,...., entity_field.fieldN
```

When you do an INSERT you put only the primary key of your entity, so you can use only primitive type.

I hope, I was clear ;)  Have a nice day